# what event is triggered in chrome when I allow camera or mic (javascript)

Tags: javascript, permissions, camera, webrtc, getusermedia

I want in my js app to know, to be notified, when I allowed (or not) the camera and/or microphone; that happens after I choose from the popup that appears when the app first time it tries to getUserMedia().

If I enable camera and mic I want to fetch the devices again with enumerateDevices(). But cannot find an even or something that happens after user clicks allow...

Comment: check my answer. I hope i understood what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/etondm56/6/

```
function hasGetUserMedia() {
  return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
}

if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
  var errorCallback = function(e) {
    alert('Reeeejected!', e);
  };

  // Not showing vendor prefixes.
  navigator.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
  }, function(localMediaStream) {
    alert('good to go');
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
      .then(function(devices) {
        devices.forEach(function(device) {
          alert(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
            " id = " + device.deviceId);
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        alert(err.name + ": " + err.message);
      });
  }, errorCallback);
} else {
  alert('cant get data');
}
```

Note that if it's already allowed you'll get the '**good to go**' alert. You'll have to remove the permission on the site you allowed camera or mic to retest.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I do something similar BUT I want this to be triggered after the allow camera or allow microphone chrome pop-up buttons are pressed, nothing in the app is ...refreshed, called, to be able to check for devices again...

Comment: yah you'll have to remove the permission to retest again cause you already did that .. for someone who did not do this it'll work as intended. Refreshing the page will look for the `video: true, audio: true` conditions. Is it clear?

Comment: I probably didn't made myself clear: what I want is that if a user logged in in my app (a react app) is going to a section of the app where is going to use camera or mic and he is prompted to allow (first time usage) camera and to allow microphone he will click let say allow and then nothing is triggered, there is no event I can catch in my app to re-fetch available devices, with labels this time, using enumerateDevices. No event I know or check for is triggered, no componenetdidupdate or anything to use to call enumerateDevices again and get the video and audio devices with proper labels.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?